# How to deal with an author name with "Jr" in Bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

I want to cite a paper. The two authors are called `Roger Koenker` and `Gilbert Bassett, Jr.` So I tried the following in my `reference.bib`

```
@article{KoenkerBassett1978, 
    author="Roger Koenker and Gilbert Bassett, Jr.",
    title="Regression Quantiles",
    journal="Econometrica",
    volume="46", number="1", pages="33-50", year="1978"
}
```

However, the appearance is strange: it took `Gilbert Bassett` as the last name and `J.` as the first (I am using the style `agsm`). What should I do to correct this issue?

Comment: Use `author = "Koenker, Roger and Bassett, Jr., Gilbert",` (and, in general, I find using braces better than quotation marks -- but this is not the source of your problem).

Comment: @Mico What do you mean with `[vonComponent]`? Could you please provide an example?

Comment: @Dox - "von" is German for "from". Various European languages, in addition to German, feature names with von-components. Here are some examples, with the von-component in bold: Kevin **de** Bruyne, Giovanni Christiaan **van** Bronckhorst, Vincent **van** Gogh, Rembrandt **van** Rijn, Charles Jean **de la** Vallée Poussin, Leonardo **da** Vinci, Piero **della** Francesca, Götz **von** Berlichingen, Peter **von** Matt, etc, etc.

Comment: @Dox - Just for fun, here are some more examples of full names with von components: Ludwig van Beethoven, Walter von der Vogelweide, Johann Wolfgang von Goethe, Franceso Maria della Rovere, Georges de la Tour, Caterina de' Medici. Observe that von components may consist of more than one word.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If a name has a "Junior" component, it needs to be entered as `SurnameComponent, JuniorComponent, FirstNameComponent, vonComponent`. Note that there are now (at least) two commas, not one. If there is no "von" component (which, N.B., could consist of more than one word), and just Jr., you would omit the final parameter (i.e., only use `SurnameComponent, JuniorComponent, FirstNameComponent`).

This is a BibTeX syntax rule that's independent of the bibliography style you employ.

Hence, you need to enter the second author's name as `Bassett, Jr., Gilbert`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{reference.bib}
@article{KoenkerBassett1978, 
    author="Roger Koenker and Bassett, Jr., Gilbert",
    title="Regression Quantiles",
    journal="Econometrica",
    volume="46", number="1", pages="33-50", year="1978"
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{natbib,har2nat}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\begin{document}
\citet{KoenkerBassett1978}
\bibliography{reference}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is also worth noting, that as seen in this question, the lack of a specification-compliant provision of "Jr." is likely to cause erroneous output. Conversely, placing 'von clauses' as a prefix of the `JuniorComponent`, will likely produce correct-looking outputs, in most cases. It is not, however, strictly specification-compliant, and can cause issues, especially in older BibTeX processing schema.

If anyone could provide a formal citation for this, perhaps in an older BibTeX specification or TUGBoat paper, I'd be interested in having that.